# ARKIT cannot scale or rotate in render method

Tags: swift, arkit

Currently playing with arkit I have a huge problem when I try to scale object inside `arkit` nodes

```
extension RecordPlaceViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

  func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    if anchor.name == "test" {
        let sceneModel = SCNScene(named: "assetsmodels.scnassets/phone2.scn")
        let nodeModel =  sceneModel!.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Plane", recursively: true)
        nodeModel?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "uv2")
        nodeModel?.scale = SCNVector3(0.1,0.1,0.1)
        nodeModel?.eulerAngles.x = -90
        return nodeModel
    }
    return nil
 }

}
```

Why those two functions do not work here ?

```
nodeModel?.scale = SCNVector3(0.1,0.1,0.1)
nodeModel?.eulerAngles.x = -90
```

If i add those with `scnkit` only it works but if i do with `arkit` node ... scale and position do nothing.

Comment: You might be getting nil back from ***let nodeModel = ...***.  Is it applying your texture from the "uv2" image?  Also, the eulerAngles are in radians, so you can't use degrees -- you need to convert, so it would be ***-90.0 * .pi / 180.0***.

Comment: yes its applying and i saw later for the radian. But that wasn't the point. I put the answer next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to implement

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)
```

instead of

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode?
```

In the first method you can do whatever you need to transform your node and this is correctly applied.